# Change CSS of dynamically created elements via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the color of the `h3` within my div `.card` that was dynamically created, however, when I reload the page, it sets its values to default.

This is how I'm trying to change the color where `color` in parameter is the desired color to apply to the `h3`.

On button click, I'm creating the card:

```
function createCard(id, title, ...) {
    // Creates a main card div
    var $cardDiv = $('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-12 card',
        "card-id": id
    });

    // h3 tag with title of note
    var $title = $('<h3>', {
        "data-toggle": 'modal',
        "data-target": '#update',
        click: function() {
            updateModal(id, title, note);
        }
    }).text(title);

    // Append to card
    $cardDiv.append($title);
}
```

After this, I'm calling the `cardScheme` method:

```
cardScheme('#29ABDA');

function cardScheme(color) {
    $('.card h3').css('color', color);
}
```

I realized that JavaScript/jQuery are unable to find the `.card` class since those cards were created dynamically.

```
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
for (var i in cards) {
    console.log('cards', cards[i]);
}
// returned {cards, 0}
```

How can I change the color of the `h3`?

Comment: you need to do this after the creation of DOM of div `.card`

Comment: so show where you are creating the divs dynamically, so that we can help

Comment: Define "dynamically created". Loaded from server? Created on clientside? ...?

Comment: where is you `h3`? add your html template

Comment: @SunilBN I am changing the color after the creation of the div and it shows up in the DOM as well.

Comment: You can look at my working code snippet below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `cardScheme('#29ABDA');` inside the `createCard` method as below.

**Note**: I can't see where you are appending the dynamic div `$cardDiv` to the document, I mean to another existing `div` or `body`.

Working `snippet`:

```js
function cardScheme(color) {
    $('.card h3').css('color', color);
}

function createCard(id, title, note) {
        
    // Creates a main card div
        var $cardDiv = $('<div>', {
            class: 'col-md-12 card',
            "card-id": id
        });
    
        // h3 tag with title of note
        var $title = $('<h3>', {
            "data-toggle": 'modal',
            "data-target": '#update',
            click: function() {
                updateModal(id, title, note);
            }
        }).text(title);
    
        // Append to card
        $cardDiv.append($title);
  
        $('#container').append($cardDiv);
    
        cardScheme('#29ABDA');
}

setTimeout(function(){
  createCard('test', 'testTitle', 'test note');
}, 2000);  // after 2 seconds
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting because I didn't have to call it inside that previously, but I guess that works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should add your JS code once the DOM is being loaded and ready to use. Like this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.card h3').css('color', color);
});
```

Comment: what if he is creating div dynamically in client side

Comment: Still he should be able to access the dynamically created divs (Not on the fly created) once the DOM is ready. Right?

Comment: OP is creating on the fly as per question.

Comment: But it shows up in the DOM when I inspect elements so how would that be on fly again?

Answer (score 0):

```
function createCard(id, title, ...) {
      ...
     // append this below the initial code you've
    //.ready make sures that function within is executed only when the specified HTML element is created in DOM
    $($title).ready(function(){
         //Then call your function
        cardScheme('#29ABDA');
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? What have you done and why is it working?

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: Explained in comments